# Does C++ let a program compiled by itself to return pointer to an array to be used directly?

Tags: c++, process, message-passing

For example, if I have some code string like this:

```
std::string code = R"( 
   #include<thread>
   #include<iostream>
   int main() 
   { 
       int array[@@size@@]; 
       std::cout<<(size_t)&array[0]<<std::endl;
       std::this_thread::sleep(1000000000);
       return 0; 
   } 
)";

boost::replace_all(code, "@@size@@", std::to_string(memSize));
```

then if I save it to a file programmatically and compile it like this:

```
system("g++ code.cpp");
```

then run it and parse its output, can I directly use the address to access the array in any way without getting segfault? Does a process have any way of sharing simple arrays to enable faster messaging or other purposes without using any other APIs?

I mean, does it have an advantage on having more freedom on accessing it if the program is compiled & run by current process, with C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as C++ is concerned, there may not even be a concept of processes. They are mentioned in the standard, as far as I can tell, only twice.

Once in a recommendation about lock-free atomics, suggesting that they should also work when shared between processes, and once with regards to possible causes of file system races.

Anything about actually sharing memory between processes would be operating system dependent, and will therefore likely require some operating system specific API calls.

Comment: Then the only way to have a dynamically (just-in-time) compiled module is to create a dll and link in run-time, right? But then it is not a process and just a reference/symbol to some functions.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik It all depends on the operating system. You didn't specify any, so I cannot say anything specific. In most operating systems there will probably be a way to access the address in the address space of the other process given sufficient permissions, which is going to work more or less well depending on what the optimizer did with the original program. All of that is going to be completely compiler/operating system dependent and without guarantees from the language standard.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Shared libraries and DLLs are also implementation-dependent features in the same way.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik For example in Linux there is [`ptrace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) which gives you basically full control of the address space of the traced process assuming you have sufficient permissions (and there are some configurations where parent processes do indeed have special privileges here). But I doubt that anything like this is going to be more efficient than just using the proper cooperative shared memory APIs offered by the OS.

Comment: ```The ptrace() system call provides a means by which one process
       (the "tracer") may observe and control the execution of another
       process (the "tracee"), and examine and change the tracee's
       memory and **registers**.``` How can ptrace access even the registers? They shouldn't have any wiring to other cores directly like that? I mean, iirc there is no assembly instruction to access register of another core.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't know how it is implemented specifically in this case, but the process will be interrupted while inspecting the registers. The OS will have stored them or maybe a CPU debug facility is used to make this more efficient. This is also how a debugger makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

Converting an integer literal to a pointer is implementation defined and might be completely meaningless. The only integer literal you can safely convert into a pointer is `0` and that turns into `nullptr`.

So, even ignoring all the stuff about processes being in different address spaces, and protected from each other on modern OSes, you still couldn't access that array in a portable way.

And you certainly couldn't access the array once the other process has finished.